# Insert script in elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am creating my site with elementor and I am installing and modifying public scripts to offer services to my users. Script example: Writing generator with choice of font in GIF. The path to the script is published on monsite.com/script/generatoroftext (example address). The script is functional but not inserted into my elementor site with my base theme. I would like to insert it in one of my sections but I don't know how, these are ZIP scripts sent to my ftp containing an index.php / css files (font)... How can I integrate them into my website with elementor? thanks in advance for your help.

I would like my script to appear in a section/column of a page dedicated to each script.